# How to replicate Stata's Wald's test (post estimation) in R

Tags: r, stata

I have the following dataset in R.

```
df<- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(50, mean=1), rnorm(50, mean=2)), 
                group = rep(1:2, each = 50))
```

And my goal is to compare the means of x in two groups using some non-parametric tests. Other than `wilcox.test(x ~ group , data=df, paired= FALSE)`, my boss recommended me to do something similar to this command in Stata

```
mean x, over(group)
 test [x]1 = [x]2
```

1- How can I replicate similar results in R?

2- What is this test doing and can this test be considered as an alternative non-parametric test for Wilcoxon test?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if this isn't what you're looking for. I don't use Stata. But if you're just attempting to take group means, this is actually pretty simple with the dplyr package.

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(mean.x = mean(x))
```

Which returns the mean from each group.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  group   mean.x
  <int>    <dbl>
1     1 1.155232
2     2 1.778388
```

If you wanted to calculate other statistics on x, by group, just replace mean(x) with another function.

Comment: Thank you so much @Richa. I don't use Stata either, that's why I am trying to find a solution in R.